# Book with an Egyptian hunchback demi-god

Tags: story-identification, books, sword-and-sorcery

As above - a rather thin book from the '60s or '70s - possibly from Daw. Yellowish cover with (I think) the main character facing right and shooting a bow. He is (also, I think) a hunchback, and either a demi-god or half god in ancient Egypt, not very well liked but a powerful warrior.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year or decade did you actually read this?

Comment: Read in the 90's, but it was picked up in a used book store

Comment: That time frame and "Egyptian gods" makes me think of Zelazny, but there aren't any covers of [*Creatures of Light and Darkness*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?13719) that match.  There is a cover of [*Isle of the Dead*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?1696) with an archer, but the gods aren't actually Egyptian.

Answer (score 16):

After a long time looking, remembering that it was a Daw title was the clue I needed.

After posting I looked through a long list of every Daw title out there, starting with the first ones in 1971.

The book is "[Crown of the Sword God](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?249356)" and is actually third in a series for "Odan the Half God"

The first is "Dream Chariots" from 1977, the second, "Whetted Bronze" from 1978 and the last is from 1980. He's actually facing to the left, not the right on the cover.

Surprising was the fact that the author, "Manning Norvil" is actually Kennith Bulmer, who wrote, among many other books, the classic Dray Prescot series under the "Alan Burt Akers" pen name.

Not a very good book from what I remember, but a forgotten "Sword and Sorcery" series. Probably would be very difficult to find them as ebooks. Goodreads and Amazon have entries on them.

Thanks to Logic and David for the comments, and for anyone else who read the post.

Comment: Well done finding it. Don't forget to formally mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, 48 hours after the question was posted.